# If statement in dynamic cluster query

Tags: dynamic, parallelization, conditional

I use a High-Performance Cluster for some of my work. I can dynamically see the state of the work but I couldn't use the If statement in the cluster query. I want to hear a sound when my work finishes.

My code follows. First I can see the state of the work then I convert it to a `String` and it is counted. If `t2` is not equal to 68, that means the work is finished. But it didn't work. Do you have any other ideas?

```
Dynamic[RemoteRunProcess[remote, "squeue -u21", 
   "StandardOutput"], UpdateInterval -> 10] // Framed
t2 = Dynamic[
  StringCount[
   ToString[
    RemoteRunProcess[remote, "squeue -u21", 
     "StandardOutput"]], _?LetterQ], UpdateInterval -> 10]
If[t2 != 68, EmitSound[Sound@SoundNote[0]]]
```

Comment: `t2` has head `Dynamic`, so it will never be equal to 68 (you are essentially doing `Dynamic[...] == 68` which is always `False`. You have to wrap `Dynamic` around the whole thing for it to work as expected, i.e. `Dynamic[t2 = ....; If[t2 != 68, ...]]`

Comment: Thank you Lukas, it works.